# Responsive triangle divs

Tags: html, css

I need to create a **responsive triangle** `<div>`. I was able to create it using **css** skewed, but it is not responsive, when I change the screen width **it gets messed up**. Can someone help me? Thank you very much in advance!

Here is what I want:

[image]

This is the code I have so far:

```css
.skewed-box-one:before {
background-color: red;
content: '';
height: 100px;
width: 30.05%;
display: block;
visibility: visible;
position: absolute;
top: -40px;
transform: skewY(8deg);
border-top: 3px solid #BBDEFB;
}

.skewed-box-one:after {
background-color: red;
content: '';
height: 130px;
width: 70%;
display: block;
visibility: visible;
position: absolute;
top: -46px;
right: 0;
transform: skewY(-4deg);
border-top: 3px solid #BBDEFB;
}
```

```html
<div class="skewed-box-one"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using fixed widths, and not with percentages?

Comment: @TobiasBarsnes yes, but it ends with the same problem

Comment: I'd give this a read https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/ .

Comment: @TobiasBarsnes thanks man, i'll read it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS `clip-path`, do note that [broswer support](https://caniuse.com/#search=clip%20path) is limited. With [this tool](https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/) you can generate the shape you want.

```css
.triangle1 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 84%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 84%);
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.triangle2 {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%);;
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  width: 50%;
  height: 300px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle1">1</div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="triangle2">2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much man, I think this is gonna work, if it does i'll post the code here!

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem with @SuperDJ help, using`clip-path`. I also find this website that helps to draw shapes:

https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Here is the final code i used:

```
.triangle1 {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(21% 96%, 0 54%, 100% 54%);
  clip-path: polygon(21% 96%, 0 54%, 100% 54%);
  background: #BBDEFB;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: -40px;
}
```

Thanks very much everybody that tryed to help and a special thanks to @SuperDJ!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea more supported than `clip-path` using background coloration

```css
.box-down {
  height:80px;
  padding-bottom:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to bottom right,red 48%, transparent 50%) bottom right/30% 50px,
    linear-gradient(to bottom left ,red 48%, transparent 50%) bottom left/70.1% 50px,
    red content-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.box-up {
  height:80px;
  padding-top:50px;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,red 48%, transparent 50%) top right/70% 50px,
    linear-gradient(to top left ,red 48%, transparent 50%) top left /30.1% 50px,
    red content-box;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  margin-top:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box-down"></div>

<div class="box-up"></div>
```